# Bring focus to select2 field upon validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a required select2 field. With this code, I can validate it:

```
$('#form').validate({
    ignore: 'input[type=hidden]'
});
```

If my select2 field is empty upon submit, I'll see an error message. The problem is it doesn't automatically focus on this field. Any other regular input field doesn't have this problem. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
$("#form").validate({
    ignore: 'input[type=hidden]',
    onfocusout: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) { 
            //validator.errorList[0].element.focus();   // for normal elements                          
            $("#" + validator.errorList[0].element.id).focus(); // for hidden elements plus others
        }
    } 
});
```